# How can I test an interface without implementing it first?

Tags: tdd

I am trying to see how test cases can drive interface design.

Now, if I have an interface with a method:

```
public interface UserService { User getNextUser(); }
```

and if UserServiceImpl is an implementation of UserService, then as per my understanding of mock objects, I should only mock the dependencies of the UserServiceImpl, like a UserRepository, because only then am I actually testing behaviour, i.e. does UserServiceImpl call UserRepository or not.

But then, if I must write a UserServiceTest, without creating a UserServiceImpl, then the only way I see is to create a mock of UserService, which doesn't seem quite right.

Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: Interfaces reflect design decisions. They may *just* be erroneous with respect to design. I don't see any way to approve good/correct design using automated tests. Interface *implementations* in contrast, can be tested in reference to their specified/expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say I completely understood what you're trying to get at with your question, but the bottom line is that you can't test a plain interface. If there's no implementation, there's nothing for a unit test to test.

The only way an interface could be "wrong" is if it doesn't fulfill its design requirements, and that's something only a human can tell.

Comment: So, the preferrred way would be, create interface, create empty implementation, write first unit test, make unit test fail, simple code in implementation to make test case pass, generalize and repeat. Is this the right approach then? So, mocks wouldn't really help here...

Comment: Actually, I would first write the (not compilable) unit test. That would force me to think about how the interface should look. I derive the interface from that, create an empty implementation, make the testcase pass...

Answer (score 0):

Your test cases should drive interface design by having a `client` be required to call `getNextUser()` on an object.  You might mock out an object for your tests of `client`.

Where there are a number of clients calling this method, you might want to create the interface at this point so that different host classes can provide different behaviour.

TDD (and obviously BDD) drives the development of behaviour.  Interfaces are a good side-effect.

Answer (score 0):

My team was thinking about testing interfaces today. We raised two questions around the subject, how and why? (We are using MS Unit Test Framework in VS2010 with CCNET to automate building and test execution)

**1. How do you test an interface?**

This article suggests defining an object implements the interface (non-explicitly I assume). You new up the object and use the is operator to see if the object implements the interface. 
http://en.csharp-online.net/Test_for_an_interface_implementation

Another approach would be to explicitly implement the interface in a class within the test project. If the test project does not build then its broken. This all or nothing approach is not a good idea because it would prevent other tests from running.

**2. What is the value in testing an Interface?**

At this time I only see the tests revealing that the interface is different than expected, meaning it changed. This would be important if you are monitoring that the design doesn't change. If your devs have access to the source for both application and test projects they could always change the test to pass when chaining the interface.